# React-bootstrap Modal with Custom trigger issue

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

The modal won't work if there's an element with `ref="xxx"` inside the modal. Example:

```
<Modal title={this.props.action + ' Virtual Software'} onRequestHide={this.handleToggle}>
    <div className='modal-body'>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="control-label col-md-2" for="Name">Name</label>
            <div className="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" ref="Name" required />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className='modal-footer'>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleToggle} className="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleAdd} className="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</Modal>
```

The modal works whenever I remove the ref="Name". Any workaround? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're hitting https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/223